# Handling data from a form to a MySQL database giving a server error

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'm having difficulties making a PHP script work . This code handles a form that should add a product to the database.

I've tried searching around for possible problems in my code, but I am totally lost. I tried rewriting my code, but nothing that I do seem to work for some reason. I am definitely  missing something.

The code is as follows.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table width="436" border="0px">
            <tr class="even">
                <td width="132"><label for="title">title</label></td>
                <td width="333"><input type="text" size="40px" name="title" value=""  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><label style=" text-align:top" for="icon_description">short description</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="icon_description" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td height="95"><label for="full_description">full description</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="full_description" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><label for="category">category</label></td>
                <td><select name="category" >
                    <?php
                        foreach(get_categories() as $category)
                        {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $category['category_name']; ?> </option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td><label for="price">price (<em>BsF</em>)</label></td><td><textarea name="price" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><label for="stock">stock</label></td><td><textarea name="stock" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td></td>
                <td style="margin-top:30px"><p style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><input type="submit" value="Add Product" /></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the same page, at the top of the document I have this code to handle the data from form and send it to the actual function that adds it to database:

```
<?php
    include_once('init.php');
    include_once('store.php');

    $products = get_all_available_products();

    if( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['icon_description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['stock']) )
    {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $icon_description = $_POST['icon_description'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $stock = $_POST['stock'];

        $errors = array();

        if( empty($title) )
        {
            $errors[] = 'You need to add a title.';
        }
        else if( strlen($title) > 125 )
        {
            $errors[] = 'Title cannot be longer than 255 characters.';
        }
        if( empty($icon_description))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Short description is empty.';
        }
        if( empty($price))
        {
            $errors[] = 'You need to specify a price.';
        }
        if( empty($stock))
        {
            $errors[] = 'You need to ad stock amount.';
        }

        add_product($title, $category, $icon_description, $price, $stock);

        header('Location: products.php');
        die();
    }
```

And the code where the add_product() function is:

```
include_once('init.php');

function add_product($title, $category_id, $description, $price, $stock)
{
    $title =  mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $category_id = (int)($category_id);
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
    $price = doubleval($price);
    $stock = (int)$stock;

    $mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` SET
                `product_name` = '{$title}',
                `product_description` = '{$description}',
                `category_id` = {$category_id},
                `price` = {$price},
                `stock` = {$stock}");
}
```

All my other code to display the products in databse is working, so connection and configuration is OK (I think). The problem is when I try to add a product, when I click the button to submit the website, it gives me a server error.

Comment: Have you looked in the server error logs?

Comment: I just checked it when I saw your comment: "[xxx.yyy.com] [Fri Oct 05 14:56:58 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xx] script not found or unable to stat: /home/domains/xxx.yyy.com/error404.html" ...

Comment: I assume that that's your Header line? Maybe try that with an absolute path instead of just `products.php`?

Comment: a filenot found error is not a fatal one. that's more of a warning. What kind of error is the server outputting? a 500?

Comment: the page is in the same root folder as products.php so...

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but this should be

```
  if( isset($_POST['title'] && $_POST['icon_description'] && $_POST['category'] && $_POST['price'] && $_POST['stock']) ) {
                   //....
}
```

instead of putting comas between them.

Comment: Well, I have another code working with using only comas to separate them and it works w/o problems. Just tried this method, but gives me a warning of code error (in dreamweaver).